# Can't fetch html element using createDocumentFromUrl

Tags: vba, dom, web-scraping

How can I use "createDocumentFromUrl()" to fetch "HTMLDocument" from a webpage directly in vba?  I tried a lot to reach out any documentation on it in SO but failed to find out. Hope there is somebody to stretch a helping hand to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I've tried so far which is definitely not right:

```
Sub HtmlScraper()
    Dim odoc As Object
    Set odoc = New HTMLDocument

    odoc.Open createDocumentFromUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "null")
    MsgBox odoc.body.innerHTML
End Sub
```

I tried like this as well but no luck:

```
Sub htmlparser()
    Dim odoc As HTMLDocument, hdoc As HTMLDocument

    Set odoc = New HTMLDocument
    Set hdoc = New HTMLDocument

    Set hdoc = odoc.createDocumentFromUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com", Null, False)
    MsgBox hdoc.body.outerHTML
End Sub
```

Comment: Also check the `.readystate` and `.busy` properties of the new document.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, it may be the site.

```
Sub test()

Dim d As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set d = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim d2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

set d2=d.createDocumentFromUrl("www.bbc.co.uk", "null")

While d.readyState <> "complete"
    DoEvents
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems that it is working cause I didn't encounter any error upon execution but how to get the html stuff. I meant where and how to use debug.print or msgbox to get the element in this very case? Thanks.

Comment: Have you googled it?  Or used intellisense from the document object?

Comment: Add this line MsgBox d2.body.outerHTML or MsgBox d2.body.innerHTML